# PDO Inserting and Execution

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

To preface things, I have very limited mysql knowledge and I decided to try and use PDO because I heard it is safer to use. That being said, if you see any injection liabilities as you attempt to help me out, let me know please! Anyways, I am having issues on how to handle the output of PDO queries, and just execution in general...

The first thing I try to do is get the form data, and search the database to see if there are any other people with the same username or the same email:

```
if(isset($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['name']) AND isset($_POST['password']) && !empty($_POST['password']) AND $_POST['password'] == $_POST['password2'] AND isset($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['email']) AND isset($_POST['year']) && !empty($_POST['year']) AND isset($_POST['termsandconditions']) && !empty($_POST['termsandconditions'])){
        $name = $_POST['name'];
            $password = $_POST['password'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        foreach ($_POST['year'] as $year);
        $termsandconditions = $_POST['termsandconditions'];

        $idqry = $sql->prepare("SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = :idcheck");
        $idqry->bindParam(':idcheck', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR,20);
        $idqry->execute();

        $emailqry = $sql->prepare("SELECT id FROM users WHERE email = :idcheck");
        $emailqry->bindParam(':emailcheck', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR, 40);
        $emailqry->execute();
```

Later on, I try to take the PDO queries checking for a duplicate username/email and create different conditions:

```
if(!eregi("^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.(edu)$", $email)){
        // Return Error - Invalid Email
        $msg = 'The email you have entered is invalid, please try again.<br />*NOTE: You must use a .edu email to be able to register!';
    }elseif($idqry != FALSE){
        $msg = "That username has already been used, please try another one.";
    }elseif($emailqry != FALSE){
        $msg = 'That email has already been used, <a class=statusmsg href="../recovery/">need to recover your password?</a>.';
    }else{
        $msg = 'Your account has been made, <br /> please verify it by clicking the activation link that has been sent to your email.';
        $hash = md5(rand(0,1000));
        $hashedpass = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);



        $sqlinsert = $sql->prepare("INSERT INTO users (username, password, email, hash, year, termsandconditions) VALUES (:username, :password, :email, :hash, :year, :termsandconditions)");
        $sqlinsert->execute(array(
                            ':username' => $name,
                            ':password' => $hashedpass,
                            ':email' => $email,
                            ':hash' => $hash,
                            ':year' => $year,
                            ':termsandconditions' => $termsandconditions));
    }
}
```

When I try to test this, I always get a $msg output of "That username has already been used, please try another one." (even if I enter a unique username)

Do you see anything wrong?
Also, is it possible to bindParam database INSERTs?
Thanks!

Comment: `eregi` functions have been deprecated long time ago. u still use ancient php version? And also, you don't need a regex if you want to validate an email address. Use built-in `filter_var()` function (>= PHP 5.2+)

Comment: I agree with @metal_fan use the built in function within PHP. Make sure you validate on the client side as well to save you some server processing. That being said, always validate on the server side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you are trying to do is this.

```
$idqry = $sql->prepare("SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = :idcheck");
$idqry->bindParam(':idcheck', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR,20);
$idqry->execute();
//This is how you get the number of rows returned
$rowCount = $idqry->rowCount();

if ($rowCount > 0){
echo 'user name taken';
}else{
echo 'user name available';
}
```

I'm sure you can work out the rest :)

Answer (score 0):

The return of the execute command is a TRUE or FALSE value depending on the success of the query therefore as long as the query can successfully execute (which means tables exist, selection is valid, mysql valid) then it'll be true. (Clarification: If the username doesn't exist your results returned is the empty set but it's still a result and therefore the query is successful.)

You should be checking that no results are returned since that is really what says that the username doesn't already exist:

```
$idqry->execute();
$count = $idqry->rowCount();

if ($count != 0) {
    // ERROR
}
```

As noted can also use rowCount() instead of fetching all like I originally used. This is more efficient then fetching all of the data even though you are trying to guarantee at most 1 result anyways.

Comment: fetchAll is going to be a bit redundant, isn't it?

Comment: Not really, I think in this case since you are limited to 1 result then it's fine. One could use fetch and just test if that returns false but in any way one needs to test the number of results returned by the query. Why do you say it's a bit redundant?